# Поведение ng-href и ng-include

Tags: angularjs

Есть кнопка, которая ведет на страницу портфолио, после клика, хочу перенаправить пользователя на элемент с конкретным id.

---

### Вот кнопка (на странице main.html)

```
<a ng-href="#/portfolio#brif">
    <div class="ibtn" >
        <svg>
           <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="166" height="45" />
        </svg>
            Заполнить бриф
    </div>
</a>
```

### Вот элемент, на который ссылаюсь (страница porfolio.html)

```
<section class="wrapp_content brif_na dark_blue" id="brif">
  <ng-include src="'template/form.html'"></ng-include>
</section>
```

Вот [приложение](http://remind.dshop24.ru/#/), на котором можно посмотреть что я имею ввиду  (т.е. при загрузке, если нажать на "заполнить бриф" - перенесет на самый верх страницы "наши услуги", вернувшись на главную и повторив действие, сошлется уже на ID, видимо ng-include не успевает загрузиться в первый раз.

---

Но если попробовать вставить такой код в controller.js

```
remindApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
});
```

А саму ссылку заменить на:

```
<a ng-href="#portfolio?scrollTo=brif" >
```

То возникает странное поведение, переход осуществляется и даже стремится к нужному месту, но не доходит до конца - вот скрины:

**ПРИ ПЕРВОМ ПЕРЕХОДЕ**

---

[image: ПРИ ПЕРВОМ ПЕРЕХОДЕ]

**ПРИ ВТОРОМ ПЕРЕХОДЕ**

---

[image: ПРИ ВТОРОМ ПЕРЕХОДЕ]

P/S: Конечно можно и не ссылаться на ng-include и писать что-нить другое, но хочется разобраться с поведением, не понимаю почему есть разница между первым и вторым способом и как сказать ng-href, чтобы срабатывала после ng-include. Заранее спасибо за терпение

Comment: добавьте рабочий пример на plunkr, в котором бы вопсроизводилась ваша проблема

Comment: @gundy, К сожалению, не знаю как создать 2 страницы на plunkr. чтобы отабразить проблему нужно 2 страницы

Comment: там в меню слева есть `new file` пункт

Comment: вот пример: [страница index.html и portfolio.html](http://plnkr.co/edit/GNsNftjBYIvhWBzHIE35?p=preview)

Comment: Если я правильно понял интересует скролл к якорю? Может быть поможет [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: Тогда предлагаю самому разместить ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в ходе разработки выяснилось что не все так просто и вопрос решился лишь наполовину

Comment: @AndreyFedorovich, можете создать plunkr с аналогичным поведением? либо, если уже решили - стоит разместить свой собственный ответ

Answer (score 1):

все решалось гораздо проще, нужно все это оборачивать в div, а этому div присваивать min-height в ссs - костыли, но действительно простой способ

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перейти по якорю, нужно добавить в адрес якорь

```
<a ng-href="#/portfolio#brif">
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9P18kSYjKgFftyI1lAT?p=preview)

Ну и как подсказал [@MichaelRadionov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480319/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-ng-href?noredirect=1#comment551487_480319) перейти можно и вручную используя  [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll)

Но так как автоматический переход по якорю включен по умолчанию, можно обходиться и без прямого вызова.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-href="'#/portfolio/'+brif">
```

Comment: данный подход не сработает, так как нужен не просто переход к адресу portfolio, но и дальнейший переход по якорю _brif_ - а для этого надо указать, что это именно якорь